# Pyspark not using TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm trying to read files from S3 using Pyspark using temporary session credentials but keep getting the error:

```
Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: null, AWS Request ID: XXXXXXXX, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXXXX
```

I think the issue might be that the S3A connection needs to use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider` in order to pull in the session token in addition to the standard access key and secret key, but even with setting the `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider` configuration variable, it is still attempting to authenticate with `BasicAWSCredentialsProvider`. Looking at the logs I see:

```
DEBUG AWSCredentialsProviderChain:105 - Loading credentials from BasicAWSCredentialsProvider
```

I've followed the directions [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#S3A_Authentication_methods) to add the necessary configuration values, but they do not seem to make any difference. Here is the code I'm using to set it up:

```
import os
import sys
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.83,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell'

sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel("DEBUG")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"))
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.session.token", os.environ.get("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"))
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
```

Why is `TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider` not being used?

Comment: how was this issue solved?

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work yet. I think wafle's response is in the right direction but it's still not working with my configuration. I'll play around with it a bit more and post here if I'm able to solve it.

Comment: setup variables in core-site.xml and copy file to spark conf folder too.its working for me using above setup

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#S3A_Authentication_methods

Comment: 2.8 seemed to do the trick. I got it working using a Spark install without Hadoop and then pointing SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH to the Hadoop classpath and using org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.4 in the PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which Hadoop version are you using?

S3A STS support was [added](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12537) in Hadoop 2.8.0, and this was the exact error message i got on Hadoop 2.7.

Comment: I am just running Spark without Hadoop and just pulling in the Hadoop dependencies to interact with S3, and perhaps that's part of the issue. I updated my packages to use hadoop-aws:2.8.0, but get the error `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsInfo;J)V from class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation`. Reading https://arnon.me/2015/08/spark-parquet-s3/ makes me think I need to set the `extraClassPath` values, but I'm not sure how to do that properly.

Comment: You need to use a matching hadoop-common version as well. The hadoop-aws jar is trying to access methods that don't exist in the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Wafle is right, its 2.8+ only.

But you might be able to get away with setting the AWS_ environment variables and have the session secrets being picked up that way, as AWS environment variable support has long been in there, and I *think* it will pick up the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`

See [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html)